# PHP Reorder Array based on timestamp and order

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in PHP (from a MYSQL call) containing an ORDER (Integer) a UUID and a MODIFIED (timestamp). The array is ordered by ORDER ascending, then by MODIFIED.

For example:

```
$resource['Resource']['id'];
$resource['Resource']['order'];
$resource['Resource']['modified'];
```

To test these I'm using the following loop:

```
foreach ($resources as $resource):
   echo '<tr><td>' . $resource['Resource']['id'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $resource['Resource']['order'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $resource['Resource']['modified'] . '</td></tr>';
endforeach;
```

On occasion, when a certain operation is carried out, the ORDER may become duplicated. For Example:

4dff97be-b0c4-45ac-a568-12f2cdbabb55, 400, 2011-06-21 15:10:35

4e01006a-d46c-4f83-8c78-0eb1cdbabb55, 400, 2011-06-21 15:15:42

When this happens I need a function to loop over the data until it finds the two duplicates (which will be next to each other of course (as the array is ordered by ORDER/MODIFIED see above). When it finds the two I need it to see which is the most recent, increment it by one, then loop over the remaining records in the array incrementing until there are no more duplicates.

This is more advanced programming than I am used to and really, really need some help. Any time anyone could give it would be gratefully accepted.

Comment: Seems like you need usort (http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). You only need to write appropriate compare function - look on examples in comments.

Answer (score 0):

This requires only one loop through. So this is going to be O(n) operations.

This problem is trivial. So don't sweat it. This will work with however many duplicates you may have.

```
<?
    $my_data = array();        
    $temp = reset($resource)
    $my_data[0] = $temp;

    $c = 0;
    next(resource);
    foreach ($resource as $one_resource)
    {
        $c++;

        if ($one_resource['order'] == $temp['order'])
        {
                $my_data[($c-1)] = $one_resource;
                $c--;
        }
        else
        {
                $my_data[$c] = $one_resource;
        }

        $temp = $one_resource;
    }

    // When the loop finishes, you'll have the data you want in the array $my_data
?>
```

Comment: `$temp = getArrayFirstElement($resource)` -> `$temp = reset($resource)` - don't code a function on your own that does the same as reset() does ;).

Comment: @hakre k, I reread your comment. You are correct. I will make the appropriate updates to the code.

Comment: Right, misread it, my fault. It's more like `list($temp) = array_values($resource);`

Comment: @hakre No, you were correct. I was being dumb. It returns the first element of the array.

Comment: @hakre if you agree with the answer, please up vote it. I need 125 points to be able to finally down vote stuff.

Comment: I've tried to implement this, but all I get returned in $my_array each time is one entry, and always the last entry from the original array. Any ideas what may be the problem?

Comment: I've updated my code above perhaps to assist, I may not have been clear that the array was multidimensional and an excerpt from a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, the easiest thing is to put all of the elements of the array into a different array.  The second array will be keyed by the order.  Otherwise, it will contain id, (order if you want to easily reuse the subarrays), modified date, and count.

As go through the original array, check if there is an entry in the second array for that order using  `isset()`.  If it is set, compare the dates and update if the current one is newer and increment the count.  If it doesn't exist, just set it and make the count = 1.

Example:

```
$new_array (
   400 => (
      id => 'blah',
      order => 400,
      modified => 'new date',
      count => 2,
   ),
   401 => (
      id => 'blah2',
      order => 401,
      modified => 'date',
      count => 1,
   ),
)
```